# Problema de consulta no banco com Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho um tabela no banco (use_shopBlock), que bloqueia um botão na view, mas quando dou um `<?php var_dump($shopBlock);?>` o resultado é `NULL`.

Minha view:

```
<?php
             $shopBlock = $this->main_model->configBlock('use_shopBlock');

                  if($shopBlock == 9){
                     echo '
                        <button type="button" id="open-shop" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Abrir Minha Loja</button>
                     ';
                  }
               ?>
```

Meu model:

```
 public function configBlock($column = false) {
        $this->db->limit(1);

        if ($column) {
            $this->db->select($column);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $query = $query->result();

        if ($query) {
            if ($column) {
                return $query[0]->$column;
            } else {
                return $query[0];
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Vou anexar como foi feita minha tabela no MYSQL
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o usuário se cadastra, adiciona o valor 8 na tabela shopBlock, e no administrador, quando alterado para "Loja Liberada", altera para o valor 9.

Este valor 9, deveria liberar o botão na view.

Código que altera valor no admin:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Ativar loja</label><br>
                            <select class="form-control" name="shopBlock">
                            <option <?=(($e && $item->use_shopBlock == '9') ? 'selected' : '')?> value="9">Loja Liberada</option>
                            <option <?=(($e && $item->use_shopBlock == '8') ? 'selected' : '')?> value="8">Loja Bloqueada</option>
                        </select>
                    </div
```

Comment: Cadê o código do post para alteração da tbl?

Comment: Se refere o código que altera o valor de 8 para 9 e vice e versa? está ali, mas o problema não é isso. O problema que não está pegando o valor na tabela.

Comment: Eu acho que a função `result( )` do CodeIgniter está retornando `null`, e portanto executando a linha `return false;` porque provavelmente a tabela está vazia.